# Updating jackson dependency in spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

My project has spring dependency bom as `<dependencyManagement>` since this comes with jackson [2.13.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.4) bom and it has some vulnerabilities, I would like to update this dependency.

Unfortunately, spring boot dependencies is not parent of my project, so a simple property update does not seems to be working. I tried a lot of things but no chance to get the version I needed.

So the question is "how can I update a dependency version that is coming from a `bom` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this by using the appropriate BOM file like this:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      ..
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
       ...
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

A very important hint is that the `jackson-bom` has to be defined in the `pom.xml` **before** the `spring-boot-dependencies` BOM. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      ..
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>VERSION</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

      ...
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: thanks, If I did not break this somewhere else, I tried and could make it work. Will update with my other tests soon.

Comment: I simply took springboot dependency management artifact to parent (just like spring does also) and it seems to be ok now.